# How to display translations in every password validation help text in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Despite the fact that password validation help texts are translated in the official Greek translation ([here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/django.po)), they don't seem to appear in my `3.0.3` application. Here's a screenshot of the custom registration form.

[image]

As you can see the only working translation appears to be the one corresponding to `MinimumLengthValidator` while the others appear in English, despite the browser's Greek language setting. I would like to know a way to introduce translations for the entirety of `help_text` bullets under the password field in the registration form.

Some crucial parts of my code

`settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 8,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'el'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('el', _('Greek')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Athens'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm, ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

User = get_user_model()

from .models import User, Profile, EmailActivation

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='E-mail',
        help_text=_('Please add a valid e-mail address.'),
    )
    accept_tou = forms.BooleanField(
        required=False,
        label=_('I have read and accept the Terms of Use.'),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            if field_name != 'accept_tou':
                if field.widget.attrs.get('class'):
                    field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' form-control'
                else:
                    field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def clean_accept_tou(self):
        accepted_tou = self.cleaned_data.get('accept_tou')
        if not accepted_tou:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You cannot register unless \
                you accept our Terms of Use")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import RegisterForm

class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:email-register")

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegisterView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["title"] = _("Register")
        context["header"] = _("Register")
        return context
```

`register.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-12">
        {% if header %}
        <h3 class="mb-3">{{ header }}</h3>
        <hr/>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method='post' action=''>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        <p>
        {% if field.name == 'accept_tou' %}
            {{ field }}
            {% trans 'I have read and accept the' %} <a href="{% url 'terms-user' %}" target="_blank">{% trans 'Terms of Use for registered users' %}</a>.
        {% else %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
        {% endif %}

        {% if field.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}

        {% if field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                {{ error }}</br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        </p>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-block btn-primary'>{% trans 'Register' %}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```